# YouTube to XBMC using Airplay

Tags: streaming, youtube, dlna

Does anyone knows a method to send YouTube videos to XBMC using Airplay? The functionality I'm looking for is similar to the one available on iOS devices.

I know that AirSync can send videos but not YouTube videos.

Comment: "similar to the one available on iOS devices" That's not a very specific description. If you add more details on what steps you want to take and what result you want, you might get more specific, more helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. I don't know if that suits you, but you can send youtube videos through web protocol. From your pc you can [add an extension to chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tubetotv/appeenhjpmpcgjlejjfogcehdancpgme).

And for android there is [yatse](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.leetzone.android.yatsewidgetfree&hl=en)

You still have to install youtube plugin for xbmc.